# Dimension 1 is fixed on the left-hand side but varies on the right ([84480 x 1] in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dimensions, fixed-point

I need to correct this code it says " Dimension 1 is fixed on the left-hand side but varies on the right ([84480 x 1]..."

I am trying to use the fixedpoint converter to convert this code. However, am having this error of dimenesion 1 is fixed on the left-hand ... for the rxWaveform

```matlab
rxWaveform = rxWaveform(1+offset:end,:);
```

```matlab
function rxWaveform = new_synch(rxWaveform,pssRef)

%PSSIndices = ltePSSIndices(enb);         % getting PSS indexes
%pssGrid = lteDLResourceGrid(enb);       % generate empty sub frame for PSS symbols
%pssGrid(PSSIndices) = ltePSS(enb);      % map PSS symbols into the subframe
%pssRef = lteOFDMModulate(enb,pssGrid); % generate PSS reference signal via LTE OFDM

% getting the lenghts of the received waveform and PSS reference signal

rxSize = size(rxWaveform,1);
pssSize = size(pssRef,1);

% performing correlation between received waveform and pss symbols
pssCorr = xcorr(rxWaveform,pssRef);  

% segmenting resultant vector to identify the first local maximum
pssCorr = pssCorr(rxSize - pssSize:rxSize + pssSize,:);

% extract the index of first local maximum, M is not useful here, just for
% the output result 
[M,index] = max((abs(pssCorr)));

%calculating offset using local maximum
offset = index - pssSize -1;  % subtracted from 1 due to shift in the 



rxWaveform = rxWaveform(1+offset:end,:);





end
```

Answer (score 0):

## There are two possible cases here, but the second makes more sense

**Case1 :**  just update a portion of the original array and return the entire array`rxWaveform`
Replace `rxWaveform = rxWaveform(1+offset:end,:);` 
by this `rxWaveform(1+offset:end,:) = rxWaveform(1+offset:end,:);`

- `rxWaveform` size let's say is `90000 by 1`
- `rxWaveform(1+offset:end,:)` size is `84480 by 1`

*Obviously those **two dimensions are different***
What you're doing is updating a portion of the original `rxWaveform`
So you need to specify that **new portion location** as well, that's `(1+offset:end,:)` on the left side

---

**Case2 :**  just return a portion of the original array `rxWaveform(1+offset:end,:)`

If you want to return only just the portion  not the entire`rxWaveform`, just change the function output name, it shouldn't be`rxWaveform` but it can be any variable name, let's say '`output`'

## The code is as follow

```
function output = new_synch(rxWaveform,pssRef)

%PSSIndices = ltePSSIndices(enb);         % getting PSS indexes
%pssGrid = lteDLResourceGrid(enb);       % generate empty sub frame for PSS symbols
%pssGrid(PSSIndices) = ltePSS(enb);      % map PSS symbols into the subframe
%pssRef = lteOFDMModulate(enb,pssGrid); % generate PSS reference signal via LTE OFDM

% getting the lenghts of the received waveform and PSS reference signal

rxSize = size(rxWaveform,1);
pssSize = size(pssRef,1);

% performing correlation between received waveform and pss symbols
pssCorr = xcorr(rxWaveform,pssRef);  

% segmenting resultant vector to identify the first local maximum
pssCorr = pssCorr(rxSize - pssSize:rxSize + pssSize,:);

% extract the index of first local maximum, M is not useful here, just for
% the output result 
[M,index] = max((abs(pssCorr)));

%calculating offset using local maximum
offset = index - pssSize -1;  % subtracted from 1 due to shift in the 



output = rxWaveform(1+offset:end,:);





end
```